# Reverse lookup on Django m2m field?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django object called "Family". "Family" has the variable "children", which is a many to many field of a class called "Child".

If I have a "Child" object, is there a way I get the family object to which the child belongs?

`Child
      some more fields...
Family
      children = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
      some more fields...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django automatically creates a reverse relationship for you in this case, so with an instance of the `Child` model, you can find all Family instances to which the child belongs:

```
c = Child.objects.get(id=1)
c.family_set.all()  # gives you a list of Families
```

Since it's unlikely a child will belong to multiple families, though, this isn't really a Many-to-Many situation. You may wish to consider modelling the relationship on a child object:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    pass # your fields here

class Child(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family)
```

This way, you can get the family for a child using `mychild.family`, and get all the children in a family using django's automatic reverse relationship `myfamily.child_set.all()`.

Answer (score 4):

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

The syntax is `child.family_set.all()` but can be changed with the `related_name` parameter.